# Moving a form does not work

Tags: vb.net

I would like to move my borderless form once a timer get's called, however, it is not doing anything. It also doesn't give an error. It just does nothing... Hope someone can help.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Debug.WriteLine("Timer has ticked. " & TimeOfDay)
    Try
        If Screen.AllScreens.Length = 2 Then
            Debug.WriteLine("Screen is connected!")

            Me.Location = New Point(Screen.AllScreens(1).Bounds.X, Screen.AllScreens(1).Bounds.Y)

        Else
            Debug.WriteLine("Screen is not connected!")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Move the form where?

Comment: To a second screen connected to my computer. That is what the allscreens(1) index is pointing to and getting the bounds from.

Comment: This is by design, using a timer makes no sense.  You'll have to do it in the form constructor, before the window is created.

Comment: Hans Passant, The timer is there to check of a second screen is available, if it is, then i want to move my form to the second one during runtime. In my form_load function it is already set.

Comment: Have you checked the value of `New Point(Screen.AllScreens(1).Bounds.X, Screen.AllScreens(1).Bounds.Y)`? Is it what you're expecting?

Comment: Yes, the values are what they need to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

```
    If Screen.AllScreens.Length > 1 Then
        ' To make it work with more than 2 screens (never tried though)
        Dim SecondaryScreenIndex As Int32 = -1

        ' Find Secondary Screen...
        ' Because it happens AllScreens(0) is not always PrimaryScreen..?
        For i As Int32 = 0 To Screen.AllScreens.Length - 1
            If Screen.AllScreens(i) IsNot Screen.PrimaryScreen Then
                SecondaryScreenIndex = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If SecondaryScreenIndex > -1 Then
            Debug.WriteLine("Screen is connected!")
            Me.Location = New Point( _
                Screen.AllScreens(SecondaryScreenIndex ).Bounds.Left, _
                Screen.AllScreens(SecondaryScreenIndex ).Bounds.Top)
            ' Try Left and Top if it makes any difference.
        Else
            Debug.WriteLine("Screen is not connected!")
        End If
    End If
```

---

> #### The following is optional

.

> **(or garbage)**

I would advise you to create a Class, like `Screen_Class` or `ScreenTools` with below content that handles the monitoring/checks on the available Screens if you plan to load more Forms...

```
' ...

Public Shared Event ScreensChanged() ' <- capture this event..
Private Shared ps_ScreensMonitor As System.Windows.Forms.Timer = Nothing
Private Shared ps_MonitorCount As Int32 = 0
Private Shared ps_PrimaryScreenIndex As Int32 = 0

Public Shared Sub BeginScreensMonitoring()
    If ps_ScreensMonitor Is Nothing Then
        ps_ScreensMonitor = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer()
        ps_ScreensMonitor.Interval = 500
        AddHandler ps_ScreensMonitor.Tick, AddressOf HandleScreensMonitoring
    End If
    If Not ps_ScreensMonitor.Enabled Then
        ps_ScreensMonitor.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

Public Shared Sub SuspendScreensMonitoring()
    If ps_ScreensMonitor IsNot Nothing Then
        ps_ScreensMonitor.Enabled = False
        RemoveHandler ps_ScreensMonitor.Tick, AddressOf HandleScreensMonitoring
        ps_ScreensMonitor.Dispose()
        ps_ScreensMonitor = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

Private Shared Sub HandleScreensMonitoring(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim i As Int32
    Dim AnythingChanged As Boolean = False

    ' Locate PrimaryScreen...
    For i = 0 To Screen.AllScreens.Length - 1
        If Screen.AllScreens(i) Is Screen.PrimaryScreen Then
            If ps_PrimaryScreenIndex <> i Then
                ps_PrimaryScreenIndex = i
                AnythingChanged = True
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    ' Find if a screen has been connected or disconnected
    If ps_MonitorCount <> Screen.AllScreens.Length Then
        ps_MonitorCount = Screen.AllScreens.Length
        AnythingChanged = True
    End If

    ' Fire the event to notify the changes.
    If AnythingChanged Then
        RaiseEvent ScreensChanged
    End If
End Sub

' WARNING !!! THIS IS NOT THREAD SAFE !
```

Then launch monitoring from your main Form constructor or Loading :

```
    ' ...
    Screen_Class.BeginScreensMonitoring()
    AddHandler Screen_Class.ScreensChanged, AddressOf HandleScreensUpdate
    ' ...

Private Sub HandleScreensUpdate()
    ' Do here whatever you want here...

    ' Get the index of the PrimaryScreen for example, 
    ' (^^ you can also make a static ReadOnly PrimaryScreenIndex Property 
    ' in the custom class above and even add a 
    ' Static ReadOnly SecondaryScreenIndex if you want)
End Sub
```

Then you could control the loading of any form depending on the members you make available on this custom Class. Making this approach useable for your requirements depends on how you're using your forms...

Comment: Thanks Karl for your suggestions. I won't be needing the class as you suggested because it's a relative small onetime project. However, the code that supplied in your first edit did not work. The me.Location does not move the form.